# Need to quickly know (CLI) whether point lies inside polygon

Tags: polygon, linux, free-software, command-line

in my app I am parsing an XML from the web which gives me such coordinate info:

I am able to use my app to get a pair of float values like 14.871381 and 50.065968. I do not want any complicate processing (using simple C++ program running in CLI) - if possible the best would be if some free library or CLI utility could say whether this point (according to the coordinates) lies in a polygon (in my case a particular region - just one) - maybe like this:

Have a map with defined polygon (region/county) A
Query: 14.871381 ; 50.065968 Reply: A
or:
Query: 14.871381 ; 50.065968 is in region A? Reply: True (or False or 1/0 or something simple)

Most important is to have really efficient and low demanding solution, no GUI needed (program runs in CLI) and it runs on weak HW (single-core Atom CPU) running Kubuntu linux and about 1-2 queries per second.

PS: my brother is able to help me with GIS related information but not with the programming...

Comment: maybe http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26519/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-near-or-inside-polygon would help

Comment: @radouxju This is good workaround, but first its in Java - so not really lightweight solution. Moreover, I am speaking about much complicated areas, that should be defined probably in tens or thousands of points.
This is map of Czech Republic, with marked areas (different colours) I am planning to work with:

http://www.krajskeurady.cz/images/mapa.gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are referring at is called "[Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) [in](http://www.ariel.com.au/a/python-point-int-poly.html) [Polygon](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/)" - if you google it you'll find various solutions with various tools of various complexity. You can pick up what ever suits you best or create your own solution.

A simple C program can be found at [stackexcange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716268/point-in-polygon-algorithm)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for and in C++ which I am using.
Thank you.